# withFormik : On initial value change, update props.value

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, typescript, formik

Once the initial props changes, the values in the forms need to be updated

```
export default withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues: (props: Props) => {
        return (
            {
                id: props.initialData.id,
                name: props.initialData.name
            }
        );
    },
    handleSubmit: (values, {  props: Props, setSubmitting }) => {
      Props.submitHandler(values);
    },
  })(NewDatasourceForm);
```

Here in `mapPropsToValues` I am able to get the new `props`, But the values in form not get updated.

```
const NewDatasourceForm = (props) => {
const {
    values,
    touched,
    errors,
    isSubmitting,
    setFieldValue,
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur
} = props;

const _handleSelect = (selectDSChoice) => {
    try {
        setFieldValue('dataSourceType',  selectDSChoice.value);
    } catch (error) {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
        console.error(error);
    }

};

return(
  <form className="needs-validation was-validated p-5" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
                className={`form-control`}
                name="name"
                type="text" 
                value={values.name} 
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
            />
        </div>
    </form>
);
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/k5w5qn94z7

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
withFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    mapPropsToValues: (props: Props) => {
```

Add `enableReinitialize: true,` solved the issue

https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/168